# Show a loader.gif image before sending the request to UrlFetchApp.fetch using AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to show loader.gif or any loading image before sending the request to UrlFetchApp.fetch. I explore the AppScript docs but couldn't find event regarding this.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('url')
Logger.log(response.getContentText())
```

Comment: You would probably need to do it on a dialog or sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SUGGESTION:**

You can use a combination of `Utilities.sleep()` ([reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer))), combined with [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) to create an HTML output of a loading animation/loader.gif (add a few JS or CSS effects to make it more presentable).

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices